# How can I force the html5 video player into full screen when the page loads?

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5-video

I'm trying to force my html5 player to go into fullscreen as soon as the page loads, I've tried with different solutions I could find around, but none seemes to work for me

Here is the code I'm working with

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Grazie e arrivederci</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stili.css">
</head>
<body onload="requestFullScreen()">
    <video width=960 height=540 id="grazieVid" controls autoplay>
        <source src="grazie.mp4"></source>
    </video>
    <script>
        function requestFullScreen() {

            var element = document.getElementById("grazieVid");

            // Supports most browsers and their versions.
            var requestMethod = element.requestFullScreen || element.webkitRequestFullScreen || element.mozRequestFullScreen || element.msRequestFullScreen;

            if (requestMethod) { // Native full screen.
                requestMethod.call(element);
            } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject !== "undefined") { // Older IE.
                var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
                if (wscript !== null) {
                    wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't. Fullscreen mode *has* to be triggered by the user.

Comment: aw man, guess my rickroll troll is going to not be fullscreen

Comment: Add an event listener to trigger the Fullscreen function. the video is played it goes full screen.

Comment: @Yuuki either stick to linking to YouTube, or use CSS to make your `<video>` element to size of the viewport.

Comment: How does the user access that `Grazie e arrivederci` page, is it from **clicking** a link/button on the same website? If yes, there might be a solution. It cannot be done if from direct pasting a link.

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 provides no way to make a video fullscreen, but the parallel Fullscreen API defines an API for elements to display themselves fullscreen.

This can be applied to any element, including videos.

Browser support is good, but Internet Explorer and Safari need prefixed versions.

An external demo is provided as Stack Snippet sandboxing rules break it.

```
<div id="one">
    One
</div>

<div id="two">
    Two
</div>

<button>one</button>
<button>two</button>


addEventListener("click", event => {
    const btn = event.target;
    if (btn.tagName.toLowerCase() !== "button") return;
    const id = btn.textContent;
    const div = document.getElementById(id);
    if (div.requestFullscreen) 
        div.requestFullscreen();
    else if (div.webkitRequestFullscreen) 
        div.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    else if (div.msRequestFullScreen) 
      div.msRequestFullScreen();
});
```